# Check if JList contains object with changing suffix

Tags: java, jlist, defaultlistmodel

I need to check if a JList / DefaultListModel contains an item. The item I am checking is a String that changes after a "$" sign.

Here is a pseudo version of the code I'm working with.

```
String theItem = "Bananas";
BigDecimal theQuantity = new BigDecimal(quantity.getText());
BigDecimal thePrice = new BigDecimal(0.00); //This changes depending on quanitity
thePrice = thePrice.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);

if (!dlm.contains(whatGoesHere)) {
    dlm.addElement(theItem + " $" + thePrice.toString());
    jList.setModel(dlm);
    //More code
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(mainPanel, "You already selected that item", "Error Dialog", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into regular expressions and pattern matching?

Comment: there could be a Listener set to the `dml` objects which gets called within  `dlm.addElement()`

Comment: Or use a class (e.g. `Product` or `Item`) to hold the description and the price, and implement `toString` and `equals` appropriately. Extra credits that way :)

Comment: @PaulHicks, would you be willing to give me a hint on how to make this class?

Comment: `public class Product { pubilc String description; pubic BigDecimal price; public override String toString() { return description + " " + price; } public override boolean equals(Object other) { /* Google how to write good equals methods */ } }`

Comment: I solved the problem by simply creating a separate DefaultListModel for validating which only contains the item.

Comment: feel free to either delete the question or post your own answer (for the benefit of others)

Comment: Provide the answer below, and accept it please. That is how we determine solved posts on this site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by making a separate DefaultListModel which contains only the selected item. This is used in the validation IF Statement.

Here is the working code:

```
DefaultListModel validatorDLM = new DefaultListModel();  //Specifically for validation
DefaultListModel orderDLM = new DefaultListModel();
String theItem = "Bananas";  //This changes with combo box
BigDecimal theQuantity = new BigDecimal(quantity.getText());
BigDecimal thePrice = new BigDecimal(0.00); //This changes depending on quanitity
thePrice = thePrice.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);

if (!validatorDLM.contains(theItem)) {
    validatorDLM.addElement(theItem);
    orderDLM.addElement(theItem + " $" + thePrice.toString());
    jList.setModel(orderDLM);
    //More code
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(mainPanel, "You already selected that item", "Error Dialog", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    return;
}
```